# How to identify web request client?

Tags: android, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, httpclient

I have a web api and 2 another apps 1 is in xamarin and another is in angularjs.

I am calling api in xamarin Using HttpClient.

I am calling api in angularjs using $http service .

Now I want to implement different logic for HttpClient call and $http call, how can I recognize the web request client?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the different User-Agent or custom HTTP header when making the web request.

You can find more details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields

Comment: Thanks @Prashant  i am doing like  this  var isHttpClientReq = string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent);